# Format JavaScript: Comma on the left side of an array element

Tags: javascript, arrays, formatting, code-formatting, formatter

I'd like to format JavaScript array literals (written on multiple lines) like this

- opening bracket is on the same line as the first array element
- comma is on the left side of array element
- one space character follows on opening bracket or comma
- closing bracket is on a separate line
- commas, opening and closing brackets have the same indentation level
- opening bracket follows on the

  - next line in case of an assignment
  - same line in case of an return statement

**Example**

```
var myArray =
  [ 'first'
  , 'second'
  , 'third'
  ];

var myMultiDimArray =
  [ [ 'first'
    , 'second'
    , 'third'
    ]
  , [ 'first'
    , 'second'
    , 'third'
    ]
  ];

function returnArray() {
  return [ 'first'
         , 'second'
         , 'third'
         ];
}
```

How can I configure which code formatting tool (usable in Sublime Text 3, Atom or Webstorm/Intellij) to apply this formatting style to my code?

**Notes**

- This formatting style is similar to [Elm's style guide](http://elm-lang.org/docs/style-guide)

  > **Goal:** a consistent style that is easy to read and produces clean diffs. This means trading aggressively compact code for regularity and ease of modification.
- This formatting style seems to be called [comma first notation](https://gist.github.com/isaacs/357981)
- **Why does the opening bracket follow on the same line in case of an return statement?**

  > The return statement is affected by automatic semicolon insertion (ASI). No line terminator is allowed between the return keyword and the expression
  >   -- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return#Automatic_Semicolon_Insertion)

**Edit**

[js-beautify](https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify) might be capable to do what I described. It has an option `--comma-first` but this option alone is not sufficient:

```
$ js-beautify --comma-first example.js
var myArray = ['first'
    , 'second'
    , 'third'
];

var myMultiDimArray = [
    ['first'
        , 'second'
        , 'third'
    ]
    , ['first'
        , 'second'
        , 'third'
    ]
];

function returnArray() {
    return ['first'
        , 'second'
        , 'third'
    ];
}
```

Comment: Note that you'll want to avoid that style if you want to `return` an array.

Comment: You can develop your own aligner or indenter package for Atom.

Comment: See https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify

Comment: I don't see this option in PhpStorm. If it existed, I would expect it to be in *Editor->Code Style->JavaScript->Wrapping and Braces*.